# Graph expression

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

The manual for the LaTeX package TikZ v. 3.0.1a states (section 19.7 "Graph Operators, Color Classes, and Group Expressions", p. 280):

> TikZ's graph command employs a powerful mechanism for adding edges between nodes and sets of nodes. To a graph theorist, this mechanism may be known as a *graph expression*: A graph is specified by starting with small graphs and then applying *operators* to them that form larger graphs and that connect and recolor colored subsets of the graph's node in different ways.

I searched Google for "graph expression" and couldn't find anything relevant. Where would a graph theorist know the term *graph expression* from? I'd appreciate references to where this term is defined, explained and used.

Comment: How about this: https://books.google.com/books?id=Fgfm5ulA0bEC&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=graph+expression+operators&source=bl&ots=-f9hX2WkjS&sig=6HzL5-vlarMEOvzfl-W8QPgfi14&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio6tGd85DWAhVN72MKHdoaC_4Q6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=graph%20expression%20operators&f=false

Comment: @Χpẘ: Looks good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book - **Recent Trends in Algebraic Development Techniques: 19th International Workshop, WADT 2008** - defines *graph expression* and discusses operators in that context. [Link](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fgfm5ulA0bEC&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=graph+expression+operators&source=bl&ots=-f9hX2WkjS&sig=6HzL5-vlarMEOvzfl-W8QPgfi14&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio6tGd85DWAhVN72MKHdoaC_4Q6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=graph%20expression%20operators&f=false)